# java there is an auto generated 270 value that I don't know where it is coming from

Tags: java

Okay a weird question.

I am trying to solve this question:

```
Given a string, compute recursively a new string where identical chars that are adjacent in the original string are separated from each other by a "*".

pairStar("hello") → "hel*lo"
pairStar("xxyy") → "x*xy*y"
pairStar("aaaa") → "a*a*a*a"
```

This is my code:

```
public class PairStar {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String word = args[0];
        System.out.println(new PairStar().change(word));
    }

    public String change(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 1)
            return s;
        if (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1)) {
            return s.charAt(0) + '*' + s.charAt(1) + s.substring(1, s.length());
        } else {
            return s.charAt(0) + change(s.substring(1, s.length()));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is:

running that code with input `rrrorrma` produce this output

**270rrorrma**

where does this 270 come from??????

Comment: You're adding `char`s together and they are treated as numbers for arithmetic purposes.

Comment: @SeanBright oh fair enough, what would be another solution please ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: `+ "*" +` would force string concatenation.